# Nesting jsonb in postgres without converting to jsonb[]

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have 1 table with 2 columns 1 is an index that holds the group number and a column of jsonb data

```
|      Index     |     payload    |
|----------------|----------------|
|       1        |     {jsonb}    |
|       1        |     {jsonb}    |
|       2        |     {jsonb}    |
|       2        |     {jsonb}    |
```

I then want to nest the payload into another jsonb, but it must not be an array.
Expected Output:

```
|      Index     |     payload    |
|----------------|----------------|
|       1        |{{jsonb},{jsonb}}|
|       2        |{{jsonb},{jsonb}}|
```

Actual Output:

```
|      Index     |     payload    |
|----------------|----------------|
|       1        |[{{jsonb},{jsonb}}]|
|       2        |[{{jsonb},{jsonb}}]|


SELECT index, jsonb_agg(payload) as "payload"
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

As you can see the output does aggregate the columns into a jsonb, but also converts it into an array. Is it possible to remove the array?

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON.  Your "actual" output is not valid JSON, either, so of course can't be the actual actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own aggregate that just appends the JSONB values:

```
create aggregate jsonb_append_agg(jsonb) 
(
  sfunc = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT index, jsonb_append_agg(payload) as "payload"
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```